# How can I suppress the command window that pops up when using Magick.NET to convert PDF images?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ghostscript, magick.net

I'm using ImageMagick.NET with C# in a Windows application to create JPG or PNG thumbnails from PDF files. My application works correctly, except a command window pops up for each PDF because ImageMagick.NET uses Ghostscript to read PDFs.

How can I suppress these command windows?

**UPDATE 11/26/2013**: The console windows pop up and disappear almost immediately, so I couldn't see what they said before. But I managed to pause a couple of them (using Ctrl-S) and found out what they said.

The first one that pops up has the title `<application path>\PDF2Thumbnail.vshost.exe` (the application is called "PDF2Thumbnail"). Its contents are:

```
**** Warning: An error occurred while reading an XREF table.
**** The file has been damaged. This may have been caused
**** by a problem while converting or transfering the file.
**** Ghostscript will attempt to recover the data.
```

Then for each PDF in the folder I'm converting to thumbnails, a window pops up with the same title `<application path>\PDF2Thumbnail.vshost.exe`, but no contents.

The thumbnails are successfully created, however.

So the problem does have something to do with Ghostscript, but I don't have any idea what the warning means.

**UPDATE #2 11/26/2013**: I did a little research and found that this error is usually caused by whatever application is generating the PDF not putting the correct end-of-line characters on certain lines in the file. Supposedly Ghostscript has been fixed a while back to ignore this, and I'm running the latest version, but still getting the warnings. So I still need to find a way to suppress the popup console windows.

Comment: This post may be of some use for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554373/suppress-messagebox-from-a-referenced-assembly

Comment: Unfortunately that post doesn't help because my application is a Windows application that is throwing up a cmd.exe window, but that post is referring to a Web application throwing up a MessageBox() window.

Comment: Not being able to see the command window, its not clear to me why you think this is to do with ImageMagick using Ghostscript. Certainly Ghostscript doesn't open a console window, and you don't need to open one to invoke GS either.

Comment: I updated the OP with more info.

Comment: Can you post a link to a corrupt pdf file? I would like to use it for testing something. Or feel free to contact me through CodePlex if you are not comfortable to post your pdf here.

Comment: Here's a link to one of the "corrupt" PDFs (though it opens with no errors in Acrobat and Chrome): http://www.doit.state.nm.us/broadband/map_gallery/regional/epcog/EPCOG_DSL.pdf

Comment: Ghostscript 'ignores' the error, in the sense that it continues to process the invalid file. In the (vain) hope that it might lead to improved production of PDF files we encourage people to report the error to the creator of the PDF file. Also, it can be useful to you to see these warnings in some cases as they can indicate why content is missing. Acrobat often ignores errors in PDF files, sometimes it may ask you on closing whether you 'want to save the changes' which is sometimes an indication of an error in the file which has been silently corrected.

Comment: You can of course redirect stderr and stdout, to a log file if required, which will presumably prevent the console window being spawned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in ImageMagick. I created a issue (https://magick.codeplex.com/workitem/1124) so you can see when this has been fixed in Magick.NET.

Comment: Thank you very much dlemstra! I suspected it was something like this.

Comment: It was a bug in Magick.NET, which has now been fixed. Thank you!